# Cómo hacer un renderizado condicional en next 14, obteniendo el pathname desde el servidor

Tags: nextjs

Estoy luchando con Next! Alguin sabe como acceder al path actual en layout.js ?? (Sin perder el server component)
Necesito renderizar condicionalmente la Navbar y el Footer.
Si alguien me puede ayudar con eso sería muy bueno. Muchas gracias!

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'
import StoreProvider from './StoreProvider'
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar/page'
import Footer from './Components/Footer/Footer'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Locations',
  description: 'Client for locations',
}


export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <StoreProvider>
          <header><NavBar /></header>
          <main>{children}</main>
          <Footer />
        </StoreProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenés a tu disposición el método `useRouter`.
Se utiliza para obtener la información de la ruta actual.
Con lo que te da el método, podés condicionalmente renderizar la NavBar y el Footer basándote en el pathname.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

Avisame si te sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener los `params` y los `searchParams` directamente del contexto de la página, échale un vistazo a [los docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page).

```
export default function Page({
  params,
  searchParams,
}: {
  params: { slug: string }
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
}) {
  return <h1>My Page</h1>
}
```

Esta forma es compatible con server components. A diferencia del `useRouter` from `next/router` que se puede utilizar **exclusivamente** en `client components`.

Alternativamente puedes user el `useRouter` from `next/navigation`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo solucioné creando layouts anidados